# Data structure for dealing with millions of record

Tags: data-structures

Which data structure is appropriate for operating over  millions of records and later need to iterate over it.

Comment: LinkedList is good

Comment: A database sounds like a good idea.

Comment: It all depends on several factors, so you should be more precise in your question :
What operations (search, order, iterate ....) ?
What kind of hardware would you use (all data in RAM, record coming as a stream ...)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What data structure to use for big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094645/what-data-structure-to-use-for-big-data)

Comment: Your information is quite insufficient. How large are the records ? What operations and access patterns do you need to perform ? (Creation/deletion/modification, sequential vs. random access, key search...) And how much is "millions" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While simple linked list might be sufficient for your needs, in case you also need to be able to maintain records in sorted order, and efficiently access records or begin iteration at a arbitrary point, I would recommend looking in to using a B-tree.

In case you want to persist it to disk, you should use a key-value store, which often use B-tree's (or LSM Trees) "under the hood" as well as providing ACID guarantees.  Examples include LMDB, BerkeleyDB, LevelDB

In short, use a database.